# Is there ever a reason in Kotlin to use threads over coroutines?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a good understanding of when coroutines in Kotlin are superior to threads.  I know that coroutines are lightweight and are great for massive concurrency when, in contrast, spinning up lots of threads is costly in compute resources, memory consumption, and possibly other ways.

I also know that coroutines are ultimately backed by threads and that, if you need, you can use a large thread pool so that coroutines can run in parallel, just like threads.

What I am unclear about if there **is ever a reason in which you should still go back to threads?**  Are there cases where threads actually result in better performance, or should I just use coroutines for all my concurrency and parallel processing needs from now on?

Comment: This is a good, but broad question, and I am not sure SO is the right platform / format to answer it. Here is my *opinion* : for one, Coroutines are multiplatform. But, on the JVM, using only **system** threads could be more performant for pure CPU tasks, as there are no coroutine or virtual thread overlay. But I am not sure it is very clear. Also, some people will say that with virtual threads, the "function coloring" of coroutines becomes obsolete. I do not agree, but still, it is a valid argument against coroutines.

Comment: Can you suggest a better place to post this question?

Comment: In stack exchange community, maybe [software engineering: Kotlin](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) is more appropriated. Otherwise, the [Kotlin Slack](https://kotlinlang.slack.com) or the [Kotlin discuss](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/) might be more responsive.